# BigQuery - Union with timestamp bug

Tags: google-bigquery

I know that BigQuery has bug, but I still would be glad to hear some ideas in order to see what is the best work around to solve it.

Union works:

```
select *
from

(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as dwh_update_date) a 
)aa
,
(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as dwh_update_date) b
```

Union doesn't work (but my query must be in this way):

```
select *
from

(select a.dwh_update_date as dwh_update_date 
from (select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as dwh_update_date) a 
)aa
,
(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as dwh_update_date) b
```

Error message:

> Field 'a.dwh_update_date.usec' not found.

Answer (score 1):

This issue been confirmed by google as temporary bug that will be fix in the future.
So for now, the best solution is to change the timestamp to string when you need to do union and cast it back to timestamp after the union.

Comment: Better to convert your timestamp to microseconds and back, with timestamp_to_usec() and usec_to_timestamp(), works nicely for me.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it removing by the "a." prefix. The sub-queries look super complicated, why do you need to do it this way?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT dwh_update_date AS dwh_update_date
  FROM (
    SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS dwh_update_date
  ) a
)aa,
(
  SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS dwh_update_date
) b
```

Comment: because of you! :)
when i'm using the query that you published with timestamp field,
i'm facing big on this issue
SELECT * FROM 
  (SELECT * FROM [oldtable] WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM [newtable])),
  (SELECT * FROM [newtable])

Comment: when i running this 
select dwh_update_date
from 
(
select dwh_update_date  from ods_dev.dwh_dim_hours 
)

,
(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as dwh_update_date) b i'm getting error : Union results in ambiguous schema. [dwh_update_date.usec] is ambiguous and is aliasing multiple fields. Aliased fields: dwh_update_date.usec,usec, it's only happend with timestamp, if i will convert it to string and back to timestamp it work


,
(select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() as dwh_update_date) b

Comment: try you to replace CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() with field from table in one of the sub query and you will the bug again..